# How do you access the "special-keys" module from an Intern functional test?

Tags: intern

How can you access the "special-keys" module from an Intern functional test?

I've tried specifying the path in the opening define statement of the test, I've also tried updating the "loader" attribute in the intern.js configuration file, but with no success so far. This must be a fairly common use case for a functional test but I've not had any luck so far and can find any examples in the source or the Git Wiki.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Intern 1.3+ you may access that module through `intern/dojo/node!wd/lib/special-keys`. Alternatively you may simply use the escape codes directly in your type/keys strings.